# How to call angularjs rest services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs, Please help.

How to get java rest services for my code.I use mockup json data.

```
var orderVariable = angular.module('ordermodule',[]);

orderVariable.controller('formController',['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {

    $scope.processForm = function() {
        alert('awesome!');  
    };

    $scope.formData = {};

}]);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
orderVariable.factory('orderableItemsService', function() {

    var orderableItemsService = {

    products:[{"name":"ACUVUE OASIS with HYDRACLEAR 6 Pack","description":{"description":"Acuvue Advance Plus contact lenses give your eyes what they need all day longsuperior comfort and moisture. Your eyes will retain the smooth sensation of a new pair of contacts thanks in large part to HYDRACLEAR technology, which builds moisture into the lens itself. Each time you blink, the built-in moisture acts as a natural lubricant for your eye. It's a refreshingly comfortable experience in a bi-weekly lens. This is the Acuvue Advance Plus 24 pack of contacts. You can also purchase this lens in a 6 pack.","details":"Details:1>LENS TYPE: 1-2 week soft disposable contact lenses.2>PACKAGE DETAILS: 24 lenses in buffered saline with methyl ehter cellulose.3>MATERIAL AND % OF CONTENT: 53% galyfilcon A.4>WATER % OF CONTENT: 47%.5>MANUFACTURER: Johnson and Johnson Vision Products, Inc., Jacksonville, FL",
        "eyeType":"LeftOD","power":"-3.21","bc":"4","dia":"11.2","boxes":[1,2,3,4],"lensType":"1-2 week soft disposable contact lenses."},
        "quantity":4,"itemid":"1","shippingaddress":"Library 1400 Chicago Ave Albany NY 12222","upc":124,"unitcost":160},
        {"name":"ACUVUE OASIS with HYDRACLEAR 6 Pack","description":{"description":"Acuvue Advance Plus contact lenses give your eyes what they need all day longsuperior comfort and moisture. Your eyes will retain the smooth sensation of a new pair of contacts thanks in large part to HYDRACLEAR technology, which builds moisture into the lens itself. Each time you blink, the built-in moisture acts as a natural lubricant for your eye. It's a refreshingly comfortable experience in a bi-weekly lens. This is the Acuvue Advance Plus 24 pack of contacts. You can also purchase this lens in a 6 pack.","details":"Details:1>LENS TYPE: 1-2 week soft disposable contact lenses.2>PACKAGE DETAILS: 24 lenses in buffered saline with methyl ehter cellulose.3>MATERIAL AND % OF CONTENT: 53% galyfilcon A.4>WATER % OF CONTENT: 47%.5>MANUFACTURER: Johnson and Johnson Vision Products, Inc., Jacksonville, FL",
            "eyeType":"RightOD","power":"-1.11","bc":"2","dia":"13.2","boxes":[1,2,3,4],"lensType":"1-2 week soft disposable contact lenses."},"quantity":4,"itemid":"2","shippingaddress":"Library 1400 Chicago Ave Albany NY 12222","upc":124,"unitcost":160},
            {"name":"ACUVUE LENS SOLUTION","description":{"description":"Acuvue Advance Contact Lens Solution.........","details":"","eyeType":"","power":"","bc":"","dia":"","boxes":[1,2,3,4],"lensType":"Contact Lens Solution........."},"quantity":null,"itemid":"3","shippingaddress":null,"upc":null,"unitcost":null}],
    checks: [],
    checkr: []
  };
  return orderableItemsService;
});

orderVariable.controller('prodCtrl1', function($scope,$http,orderableItemsService) {

    $scope.boxVal=0;
    $scope.formData = orderableItemsService;
    $scope.itemList=[];
});


orderVariable.controller('prodCtrl2', function($scope, orderableItemsService) {

    $scope.formData = orderableItemsService;
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring to do that.

Basicly you can do the following:

Create a spring project and create a file (example Greeting.java)

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Use the @RestController to get the data you need

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

and run the app with

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

nog get the date in your angular controller as followed:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}
```

Where you replace rest-service.guides.spring.io with the right address and so.

for more info please look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Where possible, please avoid posting answers that just point to another webpage. If the source is useful, quote relevant parts of it in your answer, or better still, rewrite it in your own words (you can still cite it, of course). For more information, see [answer]. Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy is it better this way?